# WSDL connect in localhost but not in Host server

Tags: vb.net, soap, wsdl

I am new to WSDL.

We have done a project on WSDL in VB and call service via PHP SOAP function which works fine in Localhost but not in live.
We came to know that problem in Default Namespace.

When tried to access the host it sent service called "GETUSERINFO" . But service sent to default as "http://tempuri.org/iservice/GETUSERINFO" and returns "Could not connect host".

Question is 
1. Why Default Namespace not connected in Host but in Local?
2. Where to change the Default Namespace?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to publish your service first and the update your reference in Visual Studio with the new address so it can generate that information for you.